# How do I fetch a log of user update changes in Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-java-sdk, changelog

I have been working on getting some information on changes made against a certain Amazon Cognito user.

However, I'm only able to fetch details specific to the Authentication flow, but now I want to fetch some user update details, for example, lets say if a user was disabled then enabled again, or if a user updates their phone number or something like that. As an admin I would want to see what has been changed or at what time was a certain change made for auditing purpose. I'm not able to find out a way how this can be achieved.

Could someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this using Cognito Streams with Kinesis streams. Once a data change happens, Cognito streams will publish the change to Kinesis streams and you can analyse data using Kinesis Streams.

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-streams.html

Comment: Will Cognito stream automatically publish all the events to Kinesis Stream or should i be do a bulk publish ?